# Insight into inheriting from a base controller class

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using .NETCore 2.1, Entity Framework, and Razor pages to create a game managing system.

I have a controller in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc namespace that connects to and retrieves data from a 3rd part API.

The controller has a number of different methods that return different things, but they all share the following code in common:

```
    public static GameSystemManager.LoginInfo gamerManagerLogin = new GameSystemManager.LoginInfo()
    {
        UserKey = "myAPIkey",
        Password = "xyzxyz"
    };

    public static GameSystemManager.GamerLister gamerLists = new GameSystemManager.GamerLister
    {
        MaxNumberResults = 15,
        PageNumber = 0
    };
```

So one controller method might look like this:

```
    public IActionResult GetAllGames(Guid Id)
    {

        public static GameSystemManager.LoginInfo gamerManagerLogin = new GameSystemManager.LoginInfo()
        {
            UserKey = "myAPIkey",
            Password = "xyzxyz"
        };

        public static GameSystemManager.GamerLister gamerLists = new GameSystemManager.GamerLister
        {
            MaxNumberResults = 15,
            PageNumber = 0
        };

        response = GameSystemManager.ListGames(gamerManagerLogin, gamerLists, Id);

        return View(response.Results);
    }
```

Since multiple controllers and methods use the same code, I decided to create a base controller, and put that code in there, and have the other controllers inherit from it.

Here is my BaseController:

```
   public class BaseController : Controller
   {

        public static GameSystemManager.LoginInfo gamerManagerLogin = new GameSystemManager.LoginInfo()
        {
            UserKey = "myAPIkey",
            Password = "xyzxyz"
        };

        public static GameSystemManager.GamerLister gamerLists = new GameSystemManager.GamerLister
        {
            MaxNumberResults = 15,
            PageNumber = 0
        };

    }
```

And here's how I use it:

```
public class GameListController : BaseController
{

    public IActionResult GetAllGames(Guid Id)
    {

        response = GameSystemManager.ListGames(gamerManagerLogin, gamerLists, Id);

        return View(response.Results);
    }

}
```

Here's my appsettings.json:

```
  "GamerManager": {
    "UserKey": "myAPIkey",
    "Password": "xyzxyz"
  },
```

Here's my GamerManagerConfig class:

```
public class GamerManagerConfig
{
    readonly string UserKey = "myAPIkey";
    readonly string Password = "xyzxyz";
}
```

However, it doesn't work. I just get a timeout error back from the API.  It *only* works when I have the code directly in the controller method, like my example above.

I think it might have something to do with the initialization.  Maybe it needs to be initialized directly in the method? I'm not sure.

Any insight would be great appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Probably posting the code that does not work would be more helpful than the code that does!

Comment: thanks! I added the base controller

Comment: @Loofer I added the way I use the base controller too.

Comment: Your login info should be in external config (user secrets, environment variables, Azure Key Vault, etc.) and you should then be injecting it into your controllers. The static with your page number and max results should not be a static either. Max results, should also likely be in your config, whereas page number should not be there at all, but rather should be coming from the request.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks, but I am just hitting the controller from my Razor pages.  How would I pass in that info?  thanks again.

Comment: Dependency injection, at least for the login info. Your max results and page number should likely be passed in as params to the action you're calling. Neither should be static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login info should be in external config (user secrets, environment variables, Azure Key Vault, etc.) and you should then be injecting it into your controllers. The max results and page number should either also be in external config or provided as params to your action (if you want to be able to customize it via the request).

Create a class like:

```
public class GamerManagerConfig
{
    UserKey = "myAPIkey",
    Password = "xyzxyz"
}
```

Bind your config to it in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<GamerManagerConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("GamerManager"));
```

Then, in your controller:

```
public class GameListController : Controller
{
    private readonly GamerManagerConfig _gamerManagerConfig;

    public GameListController(IOptions<GamerManagerConfig> gamerManagerConfig)
    {
        _gamerManagerConfig = gamerManagerConfig.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult GetAllGames(Guid id, page = 1, maxResults = 15)
    {
        var gamerManagerLogin = new GameSystemManager.LoginInfo
        {
            UserKey = _gamerManagerConfig.UserKey,
            Password = _gamerManagerConfig.Password
        };

        var gamerLists = new GameSystemManager.GamerLister
        {
            MaxNumberResults = maxResults,
            PageNumber = page
        };

        var response = GameSystemManager.ListGames(gamerManagerLogin, gamerLists, id);

        return View(response.Results);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, this is beautiful!  I'll see if I can go ahead and implement!

Comment: So I added the public class GamerManagerConfig, then added that line to my Startup.cs.  However, when adding the 'private readonly GamerManagerConfig line to the controller, it says it can't find any reference to GamerManagerConfig. I feel like I'm missing a step.  Thanks

Comment: oh wait, should "GamerManager" be a section in my appsettings.json file?

Comment: Yes. And you might need to add a using statement, depending on where you put that class.

Comment: However, don't actually use appsettings.json. in development use user secrets instead. In production you'll need to use environment variables or something like Azure Key Vault. Putting secrets in appsettings.json will have them committed to your source control which is bad.

Comment: Major progress...so I added the info to my appsetting.json (just for now), added all the code inside Startup.cs, added the needed code to my controller, however it complains that _gamerManagerConfig doesn't have a definition for UserKey or Password even though I have it in my GamerManagerConfig class as your code does. In fact, my code looks like your code now, just that I added the needed section to appsetting.json ... which I added to the main question on this post.

Comment: oh and I did have to make small changes to the GamerManagerConfig class as Visual Studio didn't like it.  The changes can be seen above.  Thanks!

Comment: finally got it working! So I see that it's injecting the UserKey and Password.  However, after all that, will I still have to "inject" that into every controller that uses UserKey and Password?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. I would suspect your static methods are linked the to BaseController.

> static methods are basically a method to fallback from object oriented
>   concepts. As a consequence, they are not very flexible in inheritance
>   hierarchies and it's not possible to do such a thing directly.

```
response = GameSystemManager.ListGames(BaseController.gamerManagerLogin, BaseController.gamerLists, Id);
```

Alternatively you could create a constructor in your BaseController. When you call the Base constructor from your GameListController it can then initialise the GameSystemManager objects with correct values. You can then Access the properties from the base class. [Link to example](https://coderwall.com/p/cibprg/basecontroller-in-asp-net-mvc)